# Can a virtual environment be used with two versions of python say 2.7.10 and 3.0?

Tags: python, installation, pycharm, virtualenv

I would like to know if a given virtual environment can be used with two Python interpreters and if so how. If not, what is the best way to switch interpreters to test the code with two versions? (Bonus: I was trying to do this from within Pycharm so any specifics on this particular IDE would be great too). There is a similar question here: [Activating the virtualenv of two different version of Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45809731/activating-the-virtualenv-of-two-different-version-of-python) but it's not exactly the same for two reasons. First, because I'm interested NOT IN TWO VIRTUAL ENVIRONMENTS but instead in using only ONE ENVIRONMENT which was not addressed there. Second, because I'm interested in alternating and as one of the responses very accurately states it, PyCharm has some tools to address this problem.

Comment: In that case you would make two virtual environments, one for each version

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Activating the virtualenv of two different version of Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45809731/activating-the-virtualenv-of-two-different-version-of-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible because virtual environments contain libraries which might be specific for different versions of Python. As to testing your code in different versions, you can use [Tox](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#basic-example)

Regarding PyCharm, it has a feature of compatibility inspection (Settings->Editor->Inspections->Code compatibility inspection) where you can specify Python versions that must be supported by your code

Answer (score 1):

In `PyCharm`, if you navigate to `File -> Settings` you can select on the left hand side menu under `Project` the `Project Interpreter` of your project. As you can see when configuring a new `venv` (i.e. pressing the gear icon on the upper right corner of your screen) you have to associate it with a specific Python interpreter.

If you want the same environment to be used by two different `python` versions you have to create two different `venvs` and associate them with each python interpreter.